# How to use angularjs to display show and hide values in different div tags?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, thymeleaf

Here is a image sample I have. [image: sample image]

Here is a plunker view of code below. https://plnkr.co/edit/ap4p6yGy5gQKc3XuP45f?p=preview

How can I use angular to show values if it is ***checked and submitted***? I am using thymeleaf framework for the UI.

**HTML code**

```
<div>
    <form>
        <h3> Values to be displayed</h3>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <input id="features1" name="features" type="checkbox"/>
                <input name="_features" type="hidden" value="on"/>
                <label for="features1">account</label>
            </li>
            <li>
                <input id="features2" name="features" type="checkbox" value=""/>
                <input name="_features" type="hidden" value="on"/>
                <label for="features2">bootfile</label>
            </li>
            <li>
                <input id="features3" name="features" type="checkbox" value=""/>
                <input name="_features" type="hidden" value="on"/>
                <label for="features3">cmts</label>
            </li>
            <li>
                <input id="features19" name="features" type="checkbox" value=""/>
                <input name="_features" type="hidden" value="on"/>
                <label for="features19">info_transaction_time</label>
            </li>
            <li>
                <input id="features20" name="features" type="checkbox" value=""/>
                <input name="_features" type="hidden" value="on"/>
                <label for="features20">node</label>
            </li>
            <li>
                <input id="features21" name="features" type="checkbox" value=""/>
                <input name="_features" type="hidden" value="on"/>
                <label for="features21">state</label>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit"/> <input type="reset" value="Reset"/>
    </form>
</div>
```

**HTML code cont**

```
<div>
    <table th:each="info : ${info}" style="width:100%">
        <tr>
            <td>account</td>
            <td th:text="${info.account}"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>bootfile</td>
            <td th:text="${info.bootfile}"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>cmts</td>
            <td th:text="${info.cmts}"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>info_transaction_time</td>
            <td th:text="${info.info_transaction_time}"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>node</td>
            <td th:text="${info.node}"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>billing_state</td>
            <td th:text="${info.state}"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

As you can see my code to display my values are in different `div` tag, therefore I can't use the inline show/hide method that angular js provides.

Example:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="Animals" name="Animals" ng-model="ModelData.Animals"/>

<div class="form-group" ng-show="ModelData.Animals">

    <label for="FirstName" class="col-md-9">
        Are you interested in Animal Liability Coverage?
    </label>

    <div style="background-color: white; position: absolute; top: 100px;left: 150px;" class="col-md-6">

        <label>
            <input type="radio" id="AnimalLiabCovY" name="AnimalLiabilityCoverageRadio"
                   ng-model="ModelData.AnimalLiabCov" value="Y"/>
            Yes
            <input type="radio" id="AnimalLiabCovN" name="AnimalLiabilityCoverageRadio"
                   ng-model="ModelData.AnimalLiabCov" value="N"/>
            No
        </label>

    </div>
</div>
```

The code above works because it is within the same `div` tag. But mine is in seperate `div` tags. What can I do?

Comment: i suggest making a jsfiddle or plunker for this.

Comment: You can definitely use Angular to do this (really easily, actually), but I don't think you should be doing it _alongside_ Thymeleaf. It won't be worth the effort to have HTML and JS files that satisfy both.

Comment: @HarrisWeinstein I need thymeleaf to display data onto my UI. I think angular would work fine with thymeleaf, I just don't know how to implement it when it is in different div tags

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `ng-show="yourVariable"` in more than one div or in your `<tr>` tag.

In your HTML:

```
<input id="features1" name="features" type="checkbox" ng-model="accountChecked" />

<input type="submit" value="Submit" ng-click="yourFunction()"/>
```

And:

```
<tr ng-show="yourVariable">
        <td >account</td>
        <td th:text="${info.account}"></td>
</tr>
```

In your controller:

```
$scope.yourFunction = function ()
{
    if ($scope.accountChecked) {
        $scope.yourVariable = true;
    }
    else {
        $scope.yourVariable = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: I want it to show once it is checked and submitted. If user checks the box it should not display until they click submit.

Comment: Edited with a function to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a quick tinker with your plunker to produce the angular result ... but I'm not sure how it will work alongside Thymeleaf:

EDIT: Modified the code so that it contains a controller (which is a better way to handle models) and an example of how the controller can use JQuery to glean values from other fields in the form that is rendered from the server.

If you need to gather values from the server AFTER the page has loaded, then we'd be going in the $http request module. It would be a good idea for you to take the Angular tutorial at W3C: http://www.w3schools.com/angular/default.asp

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//code.angularjs.org/snapshot/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
      app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
          $scope.account = $('input#_features1').val() == "on" ? true : false;
          $scope.bootfile = $('input#_features2').val() == "on" ? true : false;
      });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <div>
      <form>
        <h3> Values to be displayed</h3>
        <ul>
          <li>
            <input id="features1" type="checkbox" ng-model="account"/>
            <input id="_features1" type="hidden" value="on"/>
            <label for="features1">account</label>
          </li>
          <li>
            <input id="features2" type="checkbox" ng-model="bootfile" />
            <input id="_features2" type="hidden" value="off"/>
            <label for="features2">bootfile</label>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
        <input type="reset" value="Reset" />
      </form>
    </div>
    <div>
      <table th:each="info : ${info}" style="width:100%">
        <tr>
          <td >account</td>
          <td>{{!!account}}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>bootfile</td>
          <td>{{!!bootfile}}</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I can see that it changes the values false to to true, But how can I show values when it it is checked and submitted? Not only just checked.

Comment: Modified the code to show how to check for values after submitted (or checked before submitted). Angular is a client-side framework, so the hitch is getting the server side values to the client. If it's rendered by the server, you can pick it up from the hidden input (shown in the example). If it's a webservice call, that's another creature altogether. You'll want to learn Angular (as my answer suggests).

Comment: Okay, What about if you check both of the boxes, it becomes true, but when you hit reset. the Values stay true.